# Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/as0t0: No such file or directory (errno=2)

Tags: debian, vps, openvpn, openvz

I just attempted to install OpenVPN Access Server on my Debian VPS that uses OpenVZ. It installed fine, however when I try to start it from the administration panel, I get these errors:

```
process started and then immediately exited: ['Sat Sep 22 19:14:33 2012 Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/as0t0: No such file or directory (errno=2)']
service failed to start or returned error status
process started and then immediately exited: ['Sat Sep 22 19:14:33 2012 Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/as0t1: No such file or directory (errno=2)']
service failed to start or returned error status
process started and then immediately exited: ['Sat Sep 22 19:14:33 2012 Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/as0t2: No such file or directory (errno=2)']
service failed to start or returned error status
process started and then immediately exited: ['Sat Sep 22 19:14:33 2012 Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/as0t3: No such file or directory (errno=2)']
service failed to start or returned error status
process started and then immediately exited: ['Sat Sep 22 19:14:33 2012 Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/as0t4: No such file or directory (errno=2)']
service failed to start or returned error status
process started and then immediately exited: ['Sat Sep 22 19:14:33 2012 Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/as0t5: No such file or directory (errno=2)']
service failed to start or returned error status
process started and then immediately exited: ['Sat Sep 22 19:14:33 2012 Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/as0t6: No such file or directory (errno=2)']
service failed to start or returned error status
process started and then immediately exited: ['Sat Sep 22 19:14:33 2012 Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/as0t7: No such file or directory (errno=2)']
service failed to start or returned error status
```

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when trying to install OpenVPN on OpenVZ. You have good information at: http://wiki.openvz.org/VPN_via_the_TUN/TAP_device

Your problem could be:

- tun module is not loaded on HW-node. If you rent a VPS ask your VPS-provider for tun-device. Otherwise follow instruction how to install tun-module at HW-node.
- CT has not rights for TUN/TAP device. Follow instruction in above doc.

I can also recommend [OpenVPN page](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/admin-guides/186-how-to-run-access-server-on-a-vps-container.html) about OpenVPN/OpenVZ